# How can I only return some fields in the JSON object?

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.2

I currently have a function that returns a JSON version of an object:

```
public class Debate extends Controller
{
    public static Result viewArgument(Long id)
    {
        ...
        return ok(Json.toJson(Argument.get(id)));
    }
}
```

This `Argument` object has some confidential information that should not be exposed to the client, however. How can I select only the fields `id` and `summary` to be returned in the resulting JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler answer, just add @JsonIgnore to the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the `Argument`'s `id`and `summary` into a DTO (Data Transfer Object). Then turn that into JSON to be sent over the wire.

```
public class ArgumentDto {
    public Long id;
    public String summary;
}

public class Debate extends Controller
{
    public static Result viewArgument(Long id)
    {
        ...
        Argument originalArgument = Argument.get(id);
        ArgumentDto argument = new ArgumentDto();
        dto.id = originalArgument.id;
        dto.summary = originalArgument.summary;
        return ok(Json.toJson(dto));
    }
}
```